# How to use sed with round brackets?

Tags: sed

I have a bunch of `.php` files that I wanted to replace all occurrences of a string.

```
find: jQuery(function
replace: head.ready(function
```

I thought I was doing it right by using:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -e 's/jQuery[(]function/head.ready[(]function/g' -i'.bak' {} \;
```

What ended up happening is it replaced `jQuery(function` with `head.ready[(]function`

I was thinking I could escape the `(` by enclosing it in blocks `[]` but thats not the case.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`(` isn't a special character in sed regular expressions. You don't need to escape it.

```
sed -e 's/jQuery(function/head.ready(function/g'
```

`[(]` in a regex means a character set containing just one element, `(`. It's a convoluted way of writing `(`.

`[(]` in replacement text means the three characters `[(]`. Brackets have no special meaning in replacement text.

You can avoid repeating the function name if you like, by putting it in a group. Groups are delimited by backslash-parenthesis.

```
sed -e 's/jQuery(\(function\)/head.ready(\1/g'
```

Beware that your replacement will also affect `jQuery(functionwithsuffix`. The easy way to avoid this is to use a tool that understands extended Perl regular expressions, so you can use `(?![^A-Za-z0-9_])` at the end of the search string, meaning “followed by something that isn't an alphanumeric character”. Note that in Perl regular expressions, `(` is special, you need to prefix it with a backslash.

```
perl -pe 's/jQuery\(function(?![^A-Za-z0-9_])/head.ready(function/g'
perl -pe 's/jQuery\((function)(?![^A-Za-z0-9_])/head.ready($1/g'
```

Comment: Whether or not parens are literal or not differs between `sed` dialects, although this should be correct for most platforms.  There is only one Perl so the Perl alternative might end up being the simplest if you need a portable solution (although even then you need different quoting if you need to be portable to Windows )-:

Comment: @tripleee What bizarre sed implementation does not implement BRE (under which parentheses are literal)? Certainly not a historical Unix implementation, nor any of the major modern ones (BSD, GNU, BusyBox, …).

Comment: Sorry, I got mixed up. )-:

Comment: Is `)` similar to `(` ?

Comment: Note that in `perl` regexps, `[^A-Za-z0-9_]` happens to be `\W` (or `[^\w]`). `(?![^A-Za-z0-9_])` could also be replaced with `\b`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to escape the brackets in the replacement string.

```
sed -e 's/jQuery[(]function/head.ready(function/g'
```

Comment: I need to replace: jQuery(function with head.ready(function.... i thought i needed to escape the "(" by including brackets around it...

Answer (score 3):

`(` **is** a special character in sed, if using [extended regular expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-vs-ERE) (*ERE*).

For example, `sed -e` will fail on **Unmatched error**, when you need to escape round brackets (for whatever reason), but run *sed* without specifying *ERE*:

```
$ regex="\("; echo "...(..." | sed 's/'$regex'/_/g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: Unmatched ( or \(

$ regex="\("; echo "...(..." | sed -e 's/'$regex'/_/g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: Unmatched ( or \(
```

In such case you'll have to use sed with `-E` option (or `-r`, `--regexp-extended`):

```
$ regex="\("; echo "...(..." | sed -E 's/'$regex'/_/g'
..._...

$ regex="\("; echo "...(..." | sed -r 's/'$regex'/_/g'
..._...
```

Comment: They are _completely_ accurate. They did not mention extended regular expressions because the user in the question wasn't using extended regular expressions.  Note also that the only issue in the user's code is in the replacement text.

Comment: @Kusalananda, it's not accurate to say _"`(` isn't a special character in sed regular expressions. You don't need to escape it."_ The rest of the answer is accurate of-course.

Comment: Since `sed` uses basic regular expressions. Extended expressions with `-E` is a non-standard extension. Yes, most `sed` implementations can be _made_ to use extended expressions, and then you have to escape the parentheses, but the user here doesn't use extended regular expressions, and it's not the default type of expressions for `sed` to use.  Therefore, the other answers are not inaccurate.  Possibly incomplete, but totally accurate.

Comment: sure thing, it's all a matter of translating "not completely accurate". I removed that line, so my answer will be more accurate ;-)